# pro-discrete = locally compact and open normal subgroups have trivial intersection?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology

EDIT: After talking to some experts on the subject, I have concluded that a) the answer is not obvious or well-known for locally compact groups in general, b) the answer should be 'no' and I have some idea how to construct examples, but would rather try to write them up properly somewhere.  Perhaps this question should be closed?  Thanks for the help anyway.

This is a fairly basic question, but I can't seem to find a clear answer.

Let $G$ be a locally compact group.  Suppose that the open normal subgroups of $G$ have trivial intersection.  Does it follow that every open subgroup of $G$ contains an open normal subgroup of $G$?

If so, can the locally compact condition here be weakened?

Edit: some steps towards an answer:

- The open subgroups of $G$ have trivial intersection, so $G$ is totally disconnected.
- Any compact group satisfying the conditions is profinite and in particular pro-discrete.  (Profinite = compact totally disconnected.)
- A locally compact totally disconnected group has an open compact (indeed profinite) subgroup by van Dantzig's theorem; this compact subgroup is either finite (in which case $G$ is discrete) or uncountable.  So any non-discrete example would need to be uncountable.
- To show every open subgroup of $G$ contains an open normal subgroup, I think it would suffice to show there is an open compact normal subgroup $K$ say.  For then, given $H$ open, then $H$ contains a finite index subgroup of $K$, and so by intersecting $K$ with finitely many suitably chosen open normal subgroups we can obtain an open normal subgroup contained in $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be an infinite profinite group and let $K_n < K$ be a decreasing family of open subgroups with trivial intersection.  Thus, $K$ acts continuously on the discrete space $X = \sqcup_n K/K_n$ and this in turn gives rise to a continuous action of $K$ on the free abelian group $\mathbb Z[X]$.  Define $G$ to be the semidirect product $G = K \ltimes \mathbb Z[X]$.

$G$ is a locally compact group and if we denote $X_n = \sqcup_{m \geq n} K/K_m \subset X$ then since $K_n$ acts trivially on $X \setminus X_n$ we have that $K_n \ltimes \mathbb Z[X_n]$ is a family of open normal subgroups with trivial intersection in $G$.  Also, $K < G$ is an open subgroup but contains no nontrivial normal subgroups since the action of $K$ on $X$ is faithful.

Answer (score 0):

Take a residually finite  group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ such that no finite number of conjugates of $H$ intersect trivially, but all conjugates have trivial intersection. Now declare that subgroup and all finite index subgroups of $G$ open. $G$ becomes a locally compact non-discrete group and $H$ is open and does not contain normal non-trivial subgroups.

Comment: You have to be careful here - when you generate the topology this way, you have to make sure that the induced topology is not discrete, because then the trivial subgroup is an open subgroup. 

Comment: I assume that this is the purpose of the condition that no finite number of conjugates of $H$ have trivial intersection. But I do not know if it is enough. 

Comment: Doesn't $\text{BS}(1,7)$, the semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{7}]$ with $\mathbb{Z}=\langle t\rangle$ by $t\frac{p}{7^k}t^{-1}=\frac{7p}{7^k}$, provide an example, taking $H=\mathbb{Z}<\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{7}]$?

Comment: @Tom Church: what topology are you putting on this group?

Comment: @Tom Church: Yes, it is an example of a residually finite group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ satisfying the condition from my answer. I had in mind a more complicated example: $G=SL_3(Z)$, $H$ is a maximal subgroup of infinite index constructed by Margulis and Soifer.  

Comment: @Mark Sapir: why is $G$ locally compact?

Comment: @Colin: the subgroups of finite index are compact neighborhoods of $\{1\}$. 

Comment: @Tom Church, unknown: a countable group is totally disconnected locally compact if and only if it is discrete, so I don't think there are any interesting countable examples for this problem.

Comment: @unknown: the subgroups of finite index are not compact, since $G$ is not compact (it has an open subgroup $H$ of infinite index).  Maybe $H$ can be made compact if all the conjugates of $H$ are commensurate, but even then there is more to prove.

Comment: @Colin Reid: You are right. So a possible example is $BS(1,2)$. Of course, the group itself is not compact, you need to take its completion. But I am not sure any longer that it will work. 